# Change Mongoose Documents before find/findOne, including population

Tags: mongoose

I am looking for a way to sit right before the find/findOne functions and change the document's structure before returning the query. Not modifying permanently. Just for the response.

The same should also apply at the population, so each schema can change it's structure even before is being populated in an other schema.

The purpose is to decouple the Document's structure from the API response, and be able to have change Documents without affecting the response.

As far as I can understand, there is no appropriate hook. Is that correct? Should I implement a monkey patching solution?

Thanks

Comment: [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)?

Comment: Not permanently modification. Just for the response. I need to make sure that the response schema is not coupled to the Mongo Document.

Comment: You don't want to persist any modification to the found document?

Comment: No, I want change it's structure on the fly just for the response.

Comment: Modifying a document before finding it? Do you want to change the wording of the question or explain it better so it seems like it makes sense.

Comment: Edited. Is it better now?

Comment: pre init hook doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the pre init hook, which fires both when fetching/fetching all and when populating from another document. by @laggingreflex